# Where is the "root" in Spyder/Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Warning: Beginner Question, very frustrated...
I have Anaconda and I want to update Spyder to 3.2.6. Where should I paste this code :conda update spyder ?

Comment: Have you searched for the answer to your question on this site? Why are the solutions given in those answers inapplicable to your situation?

Comment: Yes I did. I am so newby that I could not even understand the basic thing "terminal" == root. You can delete the question, prabhat solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open Anaconda cmd Prompt and paste this command:

```
conda install spyder=3.2.6
```

Comment: It says:The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install --upgrade spyder 3.2.6

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.

Comment: yes It says correct , just run it like a simple command in cmd prompt . Don't run it in python shell . eg: C:\Users\hp>pip install --upgrade spyder 3.2.6

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) @prabhatmishra, I'm going to change your answer to `conda update spyder`. Using `pip` to install packages provided by `conda` is the source of **countless** headaches for us!